# Iterate through array of strings in NSDictionary

Tags: swift, swift3

I have an NSDictionary obtained from parsing JSON. One of the objects is an array of strings. How can I iterate through this array? I'm totally tangled up in casting everything correctly - everything I try throws up casting errors. E.g. (one of many different attempts)

```
if let answers = myDict.object(forKey: "answers") as? Array {
    for answer in answers {
        let answerString: String = answer as! String
        //do something with the string
    }
}
```

throws "String" is not convertible to "Any"

Comment: direct write let answerString = answer then it gives suggestion just take it then convert it as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is already parsed into an array of strings inside the dictionary, you should just be able to do this:

```
if let answers = myDict["answers"] as? [String] {
  for answer in answers {
    // Do something with answer (which is a String)
  }
}
```

Comment: So easy. So, to be clear,  as? [String] casts answers as an array of strings?

Comment: Correct. `as?` performs a failable cast that will return `nil` if the object cannot be cast.

Answer (score 0):

```
let ans = myDict["answers"]
if ans is [String] {
let answers = ans as! [String]
   for answer in answers {
       // Do something with answer (which is a String)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please provide additional context on how and why this solves the problem. This will improve your answers long term value.